# Decreasing for loop time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am doing a data transformation on a dataframe with 9 million records, it's taking too long to run (~20-25 mins) the loop on the entire dataframe, below is my code, can anyone please help me with increasing the speed of the for loop or any alternative to the same.
For example:

```
 account_angaza_id  cumulative_paid
0           AC002006           5000.0
1           AC002006           5000.0
2           AC002006              0.0
3           AC002006              0.0
4           AC002006              0.0
5           AC002006              0.0
6           AC002006              0.0
7           AC002006              0.0
8           AC002006              0.0
9           AC002006              0.0
10          AC002007           5000.0
11          AC002007              0.0
12          AC002007              0.0
13          AC002007              0.0
14          AC002007              0.0
15          AC002007              0.0
16          AC002007              0.0
17          AC002007              0.0
18          AC002007              0.0


for i in df_merged.index:
    if (df_merged.at[i+1,'cumulative_paid'] == 0 and df_merged.at[i+1,'account_angaza_id'] == df_merged.at[i,'account_angaza_id']):
        df_merged.at[i+1,'cumulative_paid'] = df_merged.at[i,'cumulative_paid']
        if i+1 == len(df_merged)-1:
            break
```

Result

```
 account_angaza_id  cumulative_paid
0           AC002006           5000.0
1           AC002006           5000.0
2           AC002006           5000.0
3           AC002006           5000.0
4           AC002006           5000.0
5           AC002006           5000.0
6           AC002006           5000.0
7           AC002006           5000.0
8           AC002006           5000.0
9           AC002006           6000.0
10          AC002007           6000.0
11          AC002007           6000.0
12          AC002007           6000.0
13          AC002007           6000.0
14          AC002007           6000.0
15          AC002007           6000.0
16          AC002007           6000.0
17          AC002007           6000.0
18          AC002007           6000.0
```

Any input will be helpful.

Comment: Start getting familiar to [multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas specializes in vectorised operations, so usually you can avoid a Python-level loop. In this case, you can use `groupby`. First convert `0` values to `NaN`, then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html). This assumes your dataframe is sorted by `account_angaza_id`.

```
col = 'cumulative_paid'

# replace 0 with NaN using a Boolean mask
df[col] = df[col].mask(df[col].eq(0))

# forward fill values by group, then replace any NaN values with 0
df[col] = df.groupby('account_angaza_id')[col].ffill().fillna(0)

print(df)

   account_angaza_id  cumulative_paid
0           AC002006           5000.0
1           AC002006           5000.0
2           AC002006           5000.0
3           AC002006           5000.0
4           AC002006           5000.0
5           AC002006           5000.0
6           AC002006           5000.0
7           AC002006           5000.0
8           AC002006           5000.0
9           AC002006           5000.0
10          AC002007           5000.0
11          AC002007           5000.0
12          AC002007           5000.0
13          AC002007           5000.0
14          AC002007           5000.0
15          AC002007           5000.0
16          AC002007           5000.0
17          AC002007           5000.0
18          AC002007           5000.0
```

Comment: I replicated the code, but it isn't working for only for the next row, not all the rows that satisfies the condition. Any suggestion?

Comment: @ArindamBose, Unfortunately not. I suggest constructing a *[mcve]* by editing your question, otherwise it's not trivial to replicate your problem.

Comment: Hey, I edited the question with an example, see if you could help me on this now.

Comment: @ArindamBose, Excellent edit, I have updated my answer accordingly.